# Netbeans project's disappeared from explorer

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Note: I am a beginner in Netbeans

Yesterday, i built all my projects successfully, but today I see all my projects have disappeared from the explorer.

When I try to open them , I get a message saying " XXX is not a valid netbeans project "

In every project folder , I can see SRC , TARGET and pom.xml ..

Is any file missing ? Does Netbeans also need .PROJECT file as Eclipse ?

Comment: How did you try to open those projects. Can you show us the directory layout that you have? If it is a valid Maven project you can simply use "File -> Open Project" and select the directory in which `pom.xml` is located. And no, NetBeans does not need a `.project` file. The `pom.xml` is all that is required.

Comment: Maybe there's an error in your pom.xml. If it is malformed Netbeans refuses to open the project. Check if you can build your project from the console (type in the directory where your pom is located: mvn install)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that MAVEN plugin was deactivated . Now it is OK . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Activate all the plugins that are deactivated...automatically